# Type 'JNICALL' could not be resolved ,?

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

i am trying to use the NDK in eclipse
but when following a tutorial this error pops up and i do not understand where it comes from

this is my .h file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_myproject_MainActivity */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_myproject_MainActivity
#define _Included_com_example_myproject_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_myproject_MainActivity
 * Method:    getMyData
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myproject_MainActivity_getMyData
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Error = Type 'JNICALL' could not be resolved

i also have syntax errors in the code view but these do not show up between the errors these appear with JNIEXPORT

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666711/type-jint-could-not-be-resolved-and-jnienv-jclass/12568538#12568538 Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, JNICALL is used in windows. I'm 99% sure you can add

`#define JNICALL`

(define it as a blank)

Same with JNIEXPORT.

Comment: shouldn`t these be declared in a file or system that eclipse and JDK know already, yes those defines will get rid of the errors but wil make any intended functionality void, wont it??

thanks,

Comment: Well ususally JNI.h has defines for if _WIN32_ that basically assign JNICALL to __stdcall and JNIIMPORT to __declspec(dllimport). Unix systems don't need these extra tags, so they define them away.

Comment: Solved

My tutorial neglected to mention some extra includes, apparently in their version of the ndk and eclipse these include can be added later

thanks anyhow

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols.

1. Select **Include tab** and click on **Add button** right side of window
2. Choose **include directory** from File system

For example:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\NDK\android-ndk-r10\platforms\android-L\arch-arm\usr\include.

It will ask you if you want to rebuild, click on yes...Done

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem, here is my solution. If you worked on Linux with `Java 7`, make sure these two include paths were added to you `Includes`

```
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-7-oracle/include
```